# Redis Cluster modification

Tags: cluster, redis

I have currently 2 Virtual Private Servers with 3-3 Redis instances. What I want os, to spread them to 3 VPSs with 2-2-2 nodes each. How do I do that in a way, I can keep all my keys?
I also want to reorganize the Masters and slaves to have one of each on a server.

**Existing system**

Server 1)

- 10.0.0.201:7101 (M)
- 10.0.0.201:7102 (S:7202)
- 10.0.0.201:7103 (M)

Server 2)

- 10.0.0.202:7201 (S:7101)
- 10.0.0.202:7202 (M)
- 10.0.0.202:7203 (S:7103)

**What I want:**

Server 1)

- 10.0.0.201:7101 (M)
- 10.0.0.201:7102 (S:7301)

Server 2)

- 10.0.0.202:7201 (M)
- 10.0.0.202:7202 (S:7102)

Server 3)

- 10.0.0.203:7301 (M)
- 10.0.0.203:7302 (S:7202)